# Can I convert data from string to data in a column that also contain Nulls without errors?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have a column containing dates like this: 20120418 in Access 2010.

I want to convert it to this: 4/18/2012 which I can, the problem is I get #Error in the row with null.

```
cdate(format(mydate, "####/##/##")) as myNewDate
```

How do I work around this?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use IIf

```
IIF(IsNull(MyDate),Null,cdate(format(mydate, "####/##/##"))) as myNewDate
```

Comment: Thanks Remou as always, and thanks a million everyone! I have learn something new, well it's very new to me!!